# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when writing unit tests with gtest and clang 12

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, googletest, azerothcore

I'm trying to add unit tests for some functions defined in this file:

- [src/server/game/Miscellaneous/Formulas.h](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/Miscellaneous/Formulas.h)

My test file looks like this:

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Formulas.h"
#include "SharedDefines.h"

using namespace acore::Honor;
using namespace acore::XP;

TEST(FormulasTest, hk_honor_at_level)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(hk_honor_at_level(80), 124);
    // some more checks here...
}

TEST(FormulasTest, GetGrayLevel)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(GetGrayLevel(0), 0);
    // some more checks here...
}

TEST(FormulasTest, GetColorCode)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(GetColorCode(60, 80), XP_RED);
    // some more checks here...
}

TEST(FormulasTest, GetZeroDifference)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(GetZeroDifference(1), 5);
    // some more checks here...
}

TEST(FormulasTest, BaseGain)
{
    // PROBLEM HERE
    EXPECT_EQ(BaseGain(60, 1, CONTENT_1_60), 0);
}
```

the problem arises as soon as I call the function `BaseGain` defined inside [Formulas.h](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/Miscellaneous/Formulas.h):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LoginDatabase", referenced from:
      Log::outDB(LogTypes, char const*) in libcommon.a(Log.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [src/test/unit_tests] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/test/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/test/CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [unit_tests] Error 2
```

In particular, the problem is gone if I remove the call to `sLog->outError`:

```cpp
 sLog->outError("BaseGain: Unsupported content level %u", content);
```

from `BaseGain`.

However, this issue happens only in the unit tests, the rest of the project source code compiles just fine.

To compile the project including unit tests, pass the `-DBUILD_TESTING=1` parameter to the `cmake` command.

**EDIT**: I've already tried adding `common` to the `target_link_libraries` of `src/test/CMakeLists.txt` but this hasn't solved the issue for me.

Comment: As usual with `Undefined symbols` errors, for fix the error you need to link with the appropriate library or add the appropriate source file. In you case, you need to find a library or file which **defines** symbol `_LoginDatabase`.

Comment: This problem is consistent with your unit tests not linking against the logging library (i.e. the library that defines the `Log`  class).  Ideally, your build system would know that if your tests depend on `libcommon`,  they need to link against the logging library.

Comment: @NicholasM unfortuantely if I add `llibcommon` to the `target_link_libraries` of the tests' CMakeLists.txt I get `ld: library not found for -llibcommon`. I've also tried with just `common`, it doesn't give that error but it doesn't solve the original issue either. I'm not very confident with CMake, can you please give me a hint?

Comment: You should attempt to use the exact CMake target name of your library.  For example, if your cmake file has `add_library(my_common_lib, ...)` , and `add_executable(my_tests, ...)`, you should use `target_link_libraries(my_tests PRIVATE my_common_lib)`.  You may need to post your CMake details in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by adding:

```
LoginDatabaseWorkerPool LoginDatabase;
```

to your `FormulaTest.cpp`.